# Checkbox Triggered Time Stamp for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to set multiple static time stamps that are triggered by multiple checkboxes. I've tried multiple copy and paste scripts to no avail. I did happen to find this useful script on youtube but I can only modify it to look at one column and add the stamp to another single column. Is there a way to midify this code to be able to look at several columns and input the time stamp in to several columns that correspond with the checkbox?

```
function onEdit(e) {

  let range=e.range;
  let activeRow = range.getRow();
  let activeColumn = range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = range.getValue();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    if (activeColumn == 7) {
      if (cellValue == false) {
          sheet.getRange(activeRow,8).clearContent();
    
      } else {
          sheet.getRange(activeRow,8).setValue(new Date());
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const cols = [1,2,3];
  const offsets = [1,2,3];
  const idx = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && ~idx && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    if(e.value == "FALSE") {
      e.range.offset(0,offsets[idx]).clearContent()
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0,offsets[idx]).setValue(new Date())
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this using just google sheets...I got it off a youtube video.

Basically `=ifs(A1<>true,"",G1<>"",G1,1*1,now())`
Now everytime you check the check box in A1 it will time stamp the change in G1

It prompts a circular dependency error so just turn that on (**files-->settings-->calculation** and set to 1.
It's awesome...I use it for time stamping my bills/todo list.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzLJW.jpg)